# How to disable Windows Snap Assist via command line?

Tags: windows-10, windows-snap-assist

When I press Windows+left-key or Windows+right-key, the active window snaps to the left or right side of the screen. However, when I do this, I get a selection of windows which also could be "snapped" - I found that this feature is called "snap assist".

I know how to turn it off (in settings -> system -> multitasking), but I'd like to turn it off via command line. The reason is because this needs to be disabled on a lot of computers, and I can simply add it to a script that is run on each of those computers anyway.

How can I turn off this feature via command line? Please note that I want to disable the snap assist feature, not snap assist itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using Command Prompt:

- Disable "When I resize a snapped window, simultaneously resize any adjacent
  snapped window":

```
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "JointResize" /T REG_DWORD /D "0" /F
```

- Disable "When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it":

```
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "SnapAssist" /T REG_DWORD /D "0" /F
```

- Disable "When I snap a window, automatically size it to fit available space":

```
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "SnapFill" /T REG_DWORD /D "0" /F
```

- Disable "Snap windows" toggle button:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V "WindowArrangementActive" /D "0" /F
```

#### Using Registry file:

Create a blank text file in any text editor (e.g. Notepad). Copy-paste the
following section. Then change the extension from `.TXT` to `.REG`. Double click
on that REG file to import the settings.

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"WindowArrangementActive"="0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"JointResize"=dword:0
"SnapAssist"=dword:0
"SnapFill"=dword:0
```

Restart PC to make it affect.

Answer (score 1):

This setting can be modified using the registry. You can create/modify the key `SnapAssist` which is a DWORD value. It is located/you should place it here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

0 is off, 1 is on.

You can then export it to a .reg file for deployment via a command-line, or from a batch script. You can use `reg import sample.reg` to apply it to another computer via flash drive or network share, just as an example.